# Laravel 8 vendor/livewire/livewire.js not found

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, public

I have site that run on Laravel 8. Turning on developer console I got this symptom

accessing root URL https://example.com didn't give any error

accessing login URL https://example.com/login didn't give any error

after login and redirected to dashboard URL https://example.com/dashboard give 404 errors

one of it was https://example.com/vendor/livewire/livewire.js (404 error)

but accessing https://example.com/public/vendor/livewire/livewire.js is working fine

I believe it's .htaccess things, but I don't know which one is it

I have tried many .htaccess configuration, nothing solved my problem (at least from what I can find)

Maybe there's someone in here that can help me, thanks

Here's my current .htaccess that I put on my web root folder (I didn't put .htaccess on public/ folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Configure the file `config\livewire.php`

```
'asset_url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
'app_url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
```

Then update the `APP_URL` on `.env` file